# Errors calling web service on SNI site from .net on server 2012

Tags: .net, windows-server-2012-r2, sni

On a Windows Server 2012 R2 machine I am hosting a https secured web service written in VB.NET.  It calls several third party https webservices with no problem. Recently, one of the third party sites changed their url and started using a server certificate that requires SNI, for that service I get the error 'Could not establish secure channel for SSL/TLS with authority xxx.com'

Is this a limitation of .NET (I'm using the latest one as far as I know, 4.5) or do I need to add something to the server?

If I call the same webservice from a console app written in VB.NET it will fail on an XP machine with the above error, but it works fine on a windows 7 machine.  This tell me it is the O/S, not the .net framework that is failing to recognize the certificate.

I found this:
[.NET SNI support](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26171425/net-sni-support)

but it really does not help me very much...

How can I make this work on the server 2012 box?

Thanks,
Ken

Comment: It usually has nothing to do with certificates but the change of TLS handshake. Capture network packets and compare the Windows 7 and Server 2012 boxes. Then you can find out.

Comment: I placed the code in a console app written in .net and it runs on the server 2012 when I call it from the command line.  When I call the console app from a web service I get then handshake error.  I'll look at the packets to see if that helps...

Comment: Keeping in mind that the webservice calls a console app that calls the site using SNI, If I run the webservice from IE8 (on an xp box) it works.  If I call the webservice from a VB6 app using http post the console app fails with the handshake error msg...this make no sense to me at all.

Comment: for whatever reason it is working now, I made no changes but closely followed the path of the three programs involved and now it works...thanks for the input.